# How to get filepath of selected file in windows explorer context-menu in C#?

Tags: c#, filepath, windows-explorer

I've Created a Music Player Using Visual Studio 2012 WindowsForm C#, Now I want to play/add songs from Windows Explorer as any other Player(Windows Media Player,Winamp,MpcStar,VLC...) does! so I think it wouldn't be real hard! some of these programs are simple!

so for example: I select 3 Songs in a directory in explorer and right click on them and select "Play With " and then they should use my application add function to be added to playlist and start playing! if User Press Enter key also should do this operation!

If User Select "Add to  Playlist" the songs should just added to my playlist (not replace previous playlist songs)

I don't want you to create my program I just need an answer to know how can i get paths of all selected files by windows explorer context-menu!

*** I want to get all selected files path not just single file!

** UPDATE: I found the solution! I posted the answer below! hope it helps others too :)

Comment: To be honest, your program sounds a bit annoying  You want to ignore my default media player when I launch a music file?   Huh?

Comment: I mentioned them because i checked many threads that asked something like this but people answer were about FileDialog For example!
or already i found a way to get single file path!
so i don't want to waste people time

Comment: That is the reason i mentioned them!

Comment: @EdS. it doesn't force you to play with my player!
like any other players you can choose your default player!

Comment: So many emotions for such simple problem. Just create context menu shell extension which adds new items in shell menu of audio files. Inside this shell extension you will have filenames. Or you want to use already existing menu item "Add to Playlist"? Already existing menu item "Add to Playlist" is a property of WMP and you cannot use it.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov thanks so much for your respect & politeness
can you please reference some link to me!?

Comment: also I already successfully done open my app with openwith by FileAssociation! but couldn't get the files paths

Comment: No I don't want use WMP add to playlist! I just want to add my item to context-menu if user want can disable/enable it

Comment: I am not expert in C# but maybe this link will help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang

Comment: @DenisAnisimov Thanks you so much man! :)
I hope it lead me to my goal O:) 
wish heaven for you ;) :D

Comment: even that sample haven't worked :( so i didn't continue the rest of article!

Answer (score 1):

ok Finally I've got the solution :)

this link helped me to get paths of selected files in explorer by clicking on a context-menu item:
[.NET Shell Extensions - Shell Context Menus](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus)

real easy :)

Here's The Steps:

1) Download thee SharpShell library>>

Download the 'SharpShell Library' zip file at the top of the article and add a reference to the downloaded SharpShell.dll file.

or you can download it via Nuget:

If you have Nuget installed, just do a quick search for SharpShell and install it directly - or get the package details at https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpShell.

Add the following references:

```
System.Windows.Forms
System.Drawing
```

Use these at top of your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SharpShell;
using SharpShell.SharpContextMenu;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using SharpShell.Attributes;
```

Derive your Class From `SharpContextMenu`
 Right click on the SharpContextMenu part of the line and choose `Implement Abstract Class`.

CanShowMenu

This function is called to determine whether we should show the Context Menu Extension for a given set of files. The files the user has selected are in the property `SelectedItemPaths`. We can check these file paths to see whether we actually want to show the menu. If the menu should be shown, return `true`. If not, return `false`.

CreateMenu

This function is called to actually create the Context Menu. A standard WinForms `ContextMenuStrip` is all we need to return.

Here's the whole namespace SourceCode:

```
namespace CountLinesExtension
{
[ComVisible(true)]
[COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.ClassOfExtension, ".txt")]
public class Class1 : SharpContextMenu
{
protected override bool CanShowMenu()
{
        //  We will always show the menu.
        return true;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override ContextMenuStrip CreateMenu()
    {
        //  Create the menu strip.
        var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();

        //  Create a 'count lines' item.
        var itemCountLines = new ToolStripMenuItem
        {
            Text = "Count Lines"
        };

        //  When we click, we'll call the 'CountLines' function.
        itemCountLines.Click += (sender, args) => CountLines();

        //  Add the item to the context menu.
        menu.Items.Add(itemCountLines);

        //  Return the menu.
        return menu;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    private void CountLines()
    {
        //  Builder for the output.
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        //  Go through each file.
        foreach (var filePath in SelectedItemPaths)
        {
            //  Count the lines.
            builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} - {1} Lines",
              Path.GetFileName(filePath), File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Length));
        }

        //  Show the ouput.
        MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
    } 

}
}
```

Next, we must give the assembly a strong name. There are ways around this requirement, but generally this is the best approach to take. To do this, right click on the project and choose 'Properties'. Then go to 'Signing'. Choose 'Sign the Assembly', specify 'New' for the key and choose a key name. You can password protect the key if you want to, but it is not required

Now Install and register Shell Extension:
The regasm Tool

You can use the tool 'regasm' to install and register a shell extension. When using regasm, the shell extension will be installed into the registry (i.e. the Class ID of the COM Server will be put in the COM Server Classes section and associated with the path to the actual server file), it will also register the associations.

The Server Manager Tool

The Server Manager Tool is my preferred approach for installing/uninstalling and registering/unregistering, at least during development, because it lets you install and register as separate steps. It will also let you specify whether you're installing/uninstalling etc in 32 bit or 64 bit mode.

It was the whole Sample sourceCode. we can add any number of context-menu items, any function,any fileextension,etc.

For Example I'm gonna use '.mp3' FileExtensions and change Countlines Function to a function that will send `SelectedItemPaths` to playlist and the rest of operations.

Hope this help others too!